# How can I unbreak compiz so that unity will start?

Tags: unity, compiz

I have been playing around with compiz settings, and I apparently did something that is making compiz (and therefore unity) not start when I log in. Is there a compiz settings directory somewhere I can delete to restore default settings and get unity back?

Comment: did you try `unity --reset` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 1):

This is not definitive, but I have had luck doing the following:

1. Log into Ubuntu 2D.
2. remove `~/.compiz-1` folder (~ being your /home/userid directory.  In Nautilus, show hidden folders that start with a "." by hitting "ctrl + h")
3. remove `~/.cache/compizconfig-1` folder
4. in a terminal (or probably with "alt + F2"), type `unity --reset`
5. this `unity --reset` never seems to fully complete at least for me, so I force close the terminal.
6. restart

Now free to log into Ubuntu (default 3D).  Everything seems back to normal in compiz and with Unity.

Comment: `unity --reset` *should* never close, as it becomes the running `unity` instance. Only if it fails badly would it be expected to "finish". Do you mind if I edit your post to remove that step? (If you're going to restart, it really doesn't matter whether or not you quit the running `unity` instance first, though doing so is a bit strange.)

Answer (score 0):

u can login through unity 2d . after that go to ccsm and click on the unity plugin checkbox it will tell u about conflicts, approve it and click on the middle option in all the conflict resolution dialogs, after that restart and login to unity(3d).

it may help.